# osCommerce - How to add dynamic text in the bottom of the category page?

Tags: oscommerce

I'm using CRE Loaded v6.2 B2B. It is a modified script of osCommerce.

In category page i see all the products with pagination. I want to add some dynamic text under each category. Text is unique for each category.

I should able to define the text from admin and it should display bottom of the category.

How to do this?
I mean which file i should edit? Is there any documentation available?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Probably the easiest is to add an extra text field in the category_description table. Then simply follow the trail of the category creation/editing/deleting process and add that field in the admin next to the other ones. Then you will be able to output the text dynamically on the front end of the store.

I have not used CRE Loaded in a long time, but this solution should still work.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean to add the text in the categories listing?

There are two ways to do this, one is by editing the index.php and pulling in the category description as a blurb.

There other is to use CDS (content director system) in B2B to create custom page category listings which support blurbs and images and use the URL override to point to your product categories.